# How to disable drag of QWidget with Qt::CustomizeWindowHint?

Tags: qt, qwidget

I create simple QWidget with Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint flags + fixed size (OS: Windows 7). How can I disable dragging of this window by the top border?

Window created without title bar - so it should not be draggable by mouse. Is it bug in Qt (4.8.4)?

Code:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWidget>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.setWindowFlags( Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );
    w.setFixedSize( 300, 200 );
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: sample]

UPD: please, do not propose Qt::FramelessWindowHint, because it completery removes border.

The only question is: Why dragging is available only for top border?

Reported as bug: [QT-BUG-31144](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-31144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your whole widget as disabled.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setDisabled

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enabled-prop

Or you could try making a frameless window.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/widgets-windowflags.html

Or subclass your own `QFrame`, and have it consume any mouse events on it.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qframe.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html

Hope that helps.

To prevent moving specifically in windows you can look into handling:

WM_NCHITTEST

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301402.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it is workarounds. I want to keep native frame around QWidget. I can implement windows-only solution, but I don't want to include platform-specific code.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say workarounds.  If you think that having the top edge adjusting the position instead of the size is a bug, you can report it at https://bugreports.qt-project.org/ .  Most of the time if the behavior of a widget doesn't match what you want, you just subclass what you want to change and that's that.

Comment: It's only reproducable for widgets with fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

`w.setWindowFlags( Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint );` does the trick.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's completely removes border.